# Change Matlab default x-limits behavior

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, default

If I run

```
plot(1:1001)
```

Matlab automatically sets the x range to be `1:1200`. I am aware that `xlim([1,1001])` exists, but I don't want to add this line every single time I use `plot`.

Is there a way to change Matlab's behavior so that `plot` sets the x-limits equal to the range of the data by default instead of having to do it manually every time? (For example with a flag I can set at the top of my script).

Or a parameter I can pass to `plot` to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your [default XlimSpec property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) for Axes.

```
set(0,'defaultAxesXLimSpec', 'tight')
```

Then when you plot it will use X axes tight setting for every new plot.

This will revert back to normal after you close & restart Matlab.  However, you could add that to your startup script to always apply it.

This meets some of your requirements I saw you mentioned in the comments about not using a wrapper and trying to minimize running extra commands after call `plot`

Answer (score 2):

Matlab uses an internal algorithm to determine the best interval of axis ticks. I doubt you can manipulate it and, even if it was possible, I recommend you not to do it. Such operation would change the behavior of your own Matlab installation, but everybody else using your code would stumble upon a different axis labelling probably not well fitting with your purposes.

Keep on defining your ticks manually or implement your own generalized logics into a separate function that you can release together with your scripts. [This code](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30671-calcticks) shows how to implement one, and can represent a good starting point for you.

If you want to make things simpler, create a wrapper of the `plot` function as follows:

```
h = plot_wrapper(true,1:101,1:101);

function varargout = plot_wrapper(fix_limits,varargin)

    han = plot(varargin{:});

    if (fix_limits)
        x = get(han,'XData');
        xlim(gca,[min(x) max(x)]);

        y = get(han,'YData');
        ylim(gca,[min(y) max(y)]);
    end

    if (nargout)
        varargout{1} = han;
    end

end
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking of changing Matlab's internals, I was more thinking along the lines of a flag I can set at the top of my script, or a flag I can pass directly into `plot`. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, thanks for the update. Actually, my answer is still providing a good solution, which consists of creating a wrapper of the plot function to which you can add one more parameter, signally, your flag that tells the script whether limits must be changed or not. I'll update my code to show you.

Comment: Ok, answer edited. Tell me if it can be a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. +1 for a quality answer but I won't mark it as solved yet, since it is more of a workaround than a solution. I'm looking to remove additional lines of code, which this doesn't really do, and using this would mean dragging around an extra plot-wrapper with all of my projects which reduces readability.

Answer (score 1):

You want the *x*-axis limits to tightly fit your data. If you don't mind the ***y*-axis also having that behaviour**, you can simply use

```
plot(1:1001)
axis tight
```

From the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html),

> `axis tight` sets the axis limits to the range of the data

---

If you want **only the *x*-axis** to be tight, you can do it **manually** as follows:

```
h = plot(1:1001); % h is a line object
h.Parent.XLim = [min(h.XData) max(h.XData)]; % set x-axis limits as per the line data
```

Note that the second line uses [dot notation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/access-and-modify-property-values.html), which is available since R2014b. For older Matlab versions use `set`/`get` .

---

Or you can do it **automatically** by setting the seemingly **undocumented** `'XLimSpec'` property of the axis to `'tight'`:

```
plot(1:1001)
set(gca, 'XLimSpec', 'tight')
```

which is what `axis tight` internally does (for the *x*-, *y*- and *z*-axis), at least in R2017a.